# Wordpress - Thematic Custom Post Type Loop - Child Theme

Tags: wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I'm new to Thematic, and I really like it,

I want to know what I'm doing wrong,
I got this custom post type (CPT) called "Intranet"
and in a page I want to load a custom template to run the loop with the query for showing these.

But when I try to change the loop code directly on the page template, I only got a white page.

I try it in diferent ways:

```
<?php $intranet = new WP_Query( array( 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 'post_type' => 'intranet', 'posts_per_page' => 8 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $intranet->have_posts() ) : $intranet->the_post(); ?>
```

and like this

```
<?php global $wp_query;
query_posts("post_type=intranet");
while ( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

I work before with custom post types to do this, but in Thematic didn't seems to work.
What's the right way to do this in Thematic??

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just make a file template of e.g. page-customposttypename.php